# Blackberry thread pool not working well

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, threadpool

I'm developing a thread pool in java for blackberry, this is the code I currently have:

```
public class ThreadPool {

    int maxWorkers = 15;
    Vector queue = new Vector();
    Thread[] workers;

    public ThreadPool(int maxThreads) {



        if (maxThreads <= maxWorkers)
            maxWorkers = maxThreads;

        workers = new Thread[maxThreads];


        for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++) {

            // Crea un worker que ejecuta trabajos.
            workers[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Runnable r;

                    while (true) {

                        synchronized (queue) {

                            while (queue.size() == 0) {
                                try {
                                    queue.wait();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("Error while waiting");
                                }
                            }

                            try {

                                r = (Runnable) queue.firstElement();
                                queue.removeElement(r);
                                r.run();
                                queue.notify();
                            } catch (Throwable e) {
                                System.out.println("nope!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            workers[i].start();
        }
    }

    public void addWork(Runnable work) {

        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.addElement(work);
            queue.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I queue 10 jobs, they will execute one after another, not in a concurrently way, for instance:

```
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        pool.addWork(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Random random = new Random();
                    int time = random.nextInt(5) * 1000;


                                System.out.println("I'm work " + i);

                    try {                   
                        Thread.sleep(time);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
     }
```

And I get:

```
I'm work 1
I'm work 2
I'm work 3
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing your job (i.e. `r.run()`) inside the queue synchronized statement, therefore, the queue lock isn't released until after each thread completes it's job. You should execute the job outside the synchronized statement. Try that.

Comment: Already tried @sroj answer and it worked great, remember "r" is a runnable object, it's run method can indeed be called inside a thread.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Calling `r.run()` will just call the method. You would have to pass the `r` to a Thread and call `Thread.start()` for it to run in threaded context.